# Boolean method called from another method

Tags: java, methods, boolean

Im trying to accomplish a small game on java.
This game is based on many methods.
First method, a boolean one, that give me true or false depending if i have enough lives on my game.

```java
public boolean removeLive(){
    this.wastedLives++;
    if(this.wastedLives == this.lives) {
        restingLives=false;
        System.out.println("GAME OVER");
    }
    if(this.wastedLives < this.lives) {
        restingLives=true;
    }
    return restingLives;
}
```

So if I instance a call for this method it do what's supposed to do, because in other method (calculateLives) i achieve the value of lives=startLives-wastedLives;

So now, i need to design another method that generate a random number and I have to guess.

```java
public void Play() {
    super.rebootGame(); 
    boolean continue=true;
    System.out.println("Choose a number between 1 &100: ");
    this.myNumber=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()); 
    while(this.myNumber < 1 || this.myNumber > 100) {
        System.out.println("Choose again a number between the range");
        this.myNumber=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    }
    this.randomN = generateRandomNumber();//Method that generate the random number (int)(Math.random()*100)+1;
    setStartingLives(5);
    while (continue == true && removeLive() == true) {
        if (this.myNumber == this.randomN) {
            System.out.println("U WIN!!");
            refreshRecord();
            continue = false;
        } else {
            removeLive();
            if(continue == true && removeLive() == true) {
                if(this.myNumber > this.randomN) {
                    System.out.println("U have too find a lower number");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("U have too find a higher number");
                }
                this.myNumber = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            }                          
        }   
    }
}
```

The problem is that the first method, the boolean one, seems not to be called and i dont know why. Because im setting the Starting lives and im requesting to removeLive every time i do not guess the random number.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the poor translation.

Comment: "continue" is a java reserved keyword, do not use it as variable. Use something else like "continueGame"

Comment: Why do you think the method is not called? You're probably removing lives more than you should before the game even starts you already invoke this method at your loop.
And as @AtulKumarVerma said, `continue` is a java reserved keyword, I'm surprised your class even compiles

Comment: yep. Atul is right, but is a translation of continue from spanish (in the program im just calling continua). And Marcos Barbero, you're right too, i was calling the method several times. I fixed both errors.
Thank you guys for staying there to help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, im a bit dumb owin to CoVid19, so too many ours in front of screen doesent help to have a clear mind.

1st of all, the first IF just below of the 2nd while needs another condition, because without it, it will be on an infinite loop.

```
while (continue==true&&removeLive()==true){
            if (this.myNumber==this.randomN){
                System.out.println("U WIN!!");
                refreshRecord();
                continue=false;
            } else{
                removeLive();
                if(continue==true&&removeLive()==true){
                    if(this.myNumber>this.randomN){
                    System.out.println("U have too find a lower number");
                    }
                    else{
                    System.out.println("U have too find a higher number");
                    }
                    this.myNumber=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                }                          
            }
```

And it must have another if or else to finish the loop.

```
while (continue==true&&removeLive()==true){
            if (this.myNumber==this.randomN){
                System.out.println("U WIN!!");
                refreshRecord();
                continue=false;
            } else{
                removeLive();
                if(continue==true&&removeLive()==true){
                    if(this.myNumber>this.randomN){
                    System.out.println("U have too find a lower number");
                    }
                    else{
                    System.out.println("U have too find a higher number");
                    }
                    this.myNumber=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                }                          
            }   **if(super.getRestingLives()==false){
                      continue==false;
                    }**
```

Second thing that I missed.
My boolean method return me a boolean, but each call i made, also rest a live. So i need a getter method to get the value of the boolean

```
public boolean getRestingLives(){
        return restingLives;
    }
```

And the third and no less important, is that i was making a wrong call to the super.parameters. 
So I added the proper call

```
        super.setStartingLives(this.startLives);
    super.calculateRestingLives(super.getStartingLives());
```

Sorry for mess up the threads, but sometimes its necesary to make questions to get your own answers.